# Converting $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\varepsilon s} \, (s+s^2)^{\beta}}{\log^{\gamma}((1+s)/s)} \, ds$ to a sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, generating-functions, closed-form

Could anyone shed some light on how to convert the following integral to a sum?
$$ I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\varepsilon s} \, (s+s^2)^{\beta}}{\log^{\gamma}((1+s)/s)}  \, ds; \qquad\,\,\varepsilon,\beta,\gamma>0$$

With $t=\log((1+s)/s)$, we get
$$ I=I_3=e\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{e^t-1}} \, e^{\beta t}}{t^{\gamma} \left(e^t-1\right)^{2\beta+2}}  \, dt=??$$

Using the generalized Bernoulli polynomials $B^\alpha_n(x)$ of order $\alpha$ defined by the generating function
$$\frac{t^\alpha e^{xt}}{(e^{t}-1)^\alpha} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n^\alpha(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}, \qquad (*)$$
Then, for $x=0$ and $\alpha=2\beta+2$, we get
$$ \frac{t^{2\beta+2}}{ \left(e^t-1\right)^{2\beta+2}} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n^{2\beta+2}(0) \frac{t^n}{n!}. $$
Invert the sum & integral, $I$ read as
\begin{align*}
I=e\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{e^t-1}} e^{\beta t}}{t^{\gamma} \left(e^t-1\right)^{2\beta+2}}  \, dt= e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n^{2\beta+2}(0)}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{e^t-1}}e^{\beta t}}{t^{\gamma+2\beta-n+2}} dt. 
\end{align*}
It remains to calculate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{e^t-1}} e^{\beta t}}{t^{\gamma+2\beta-n+2}} dt=?$.

But some references they impose the condition $|t|<2\pi$ to use the formula $(*)$. In my case $t\geq 0$. I don't know, is this condition ($|t|<2\pi$) necessary to write the formula $(*)$?

**If not, another trick for converting integral $I$ to a sum (in terms of some special functions)??**

Comment: What have you tried thus far??

Comment: @Hans Olo, I made some change of variable, but without success.

Comment: What is $\log(t)^\gamma$? Is it $(\log(t))^\gamma$?

Comment: @xpaul, yes it is $(\log(t))^{\gamma}$

Comment: I'm not sure if it's useful, but the integral can be transformed into the series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^{(\gamma)}(0)}{n!} \Gamma(1+\beta+\gamma-n) \: U(1+\beta+\gamma-n,2 +2\beta+\gamma-n,a) $$ where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric series and $B$ is Carlitz's generalization of the Jordan Polynomials. ( *A note on Bernoulli and Euler polynomials of the second kind*. Scripta Math., vol. 25, pp. 323–330,1961)

Comment: @ DecarbonatedOdes, the above reference is not available, another reference?

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes, what is $a$? and can you write the formula with these conditions on these parameters as it is in the reference?

Comment: @Z.Alfata I'm sorry, I don't have a different reference on hand. I can try and dig up another for you. Also, $a$ is supposed to be $\alpha$ as in your post; I merely typed the letter wrong.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes thank you for your message.  I found the reference of "L Carlitz", for that I modified my question above. I think the formula you quoted comes from formula (∗) above. Moreover,  in the paper of "L Carlitz", there is no condition on $t$! Is this condition $(|t|<2\pi)$ necessary to write the formula (∗)?

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes, If you can explain how you got to the sum and make your proposed solution an answer!

Comment: Dear @DecarbonatedOdes, if can help me and answer this question i would be very grateful to your. thank you in advance.

Comment: @Z.Alfata It is the user’s choice if they answer.

Comment: As a guess, it looks like an expansion, like in the question, was done with the Generalized Bernoulli polynomials  and the rest was integration by @DecarbonatedOdes

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash, Yes, but the problem is, to use the formula $(*)$ it is necessary that $|t|<2\pi$ and in my case $t\geq 0$ (beacause $\int_0^{\infty} ... dt$).